# Extrema in two variables of a sum of logs, or equation with sum of rational functions

Tags: numerical-methods, rational-functions

I am trying to find numerically $\arg\min_{x\in(1, +\infty),y\in(0, 1)}\sum_i\log(xy+\alpha_ix+\beta_iy+\gamma_i)$, where the sum has a large number of terms, and the coefficients are such that the expression is always defined ($\alpha_i, \gamma_i$>0, $\beta_i>-1$).

Of course, one can rephrase this as trying to solve the following system:
$\sum_i\frac{y+\alpha_i}{xy+\alpha_ix+\beta_iy+\gamma_i}=\sum_i\frac{x+\beta_iy}{xy+\alpha_ix+\beta_iy+\gamma_i}=0$.

Is there any theory behind this kind of equations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90323/extrema-in-two-variables-of-a-sum-of-logs-or-equation-with-sum-of-rational-funct. That's very bad form.